# Input field value is not added to field history when the is submitted from javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, input, autocomplete

Does anybody know how to add the value of an input field to the history of that input field when the form is submitted from javascript in Chrome? (The problem does not appear in Firefox.) Or what do I have to enable? autocomplete='on' does not work on the input field.

For example, in a login form it is nice to have the browser remember the login such that the user does not need to input it again.

I am currently submitting the form with jQuery's submit() method on the form object but the user field does not remember the login name when I load the page again?

This works if I submit the form using a submit button.

Comment: If this is important, the form is also added to the page through javasctipt.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no way to do this programmatically via Javascript. To ensure support across browsers and submission types, I would recommend implementing your own autocomplete and maintaining the history. There are lots of libraries out there for autocomplete and storage/retrieval via ajax should be elementary. Let me know if you need further guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my use case is not very suitable for auto-completion. It's the login form and you don't want to start showing all user accounts in there :). I only need the simple browser input field history. I my case I have another solution which is pre-populating the field with the most recent user login (and probably only enable this feature on mobile devices).

Comment: You don't have to show all user accounts -- just store attempts in the browser's localStorage.

Comment: Yup, that would be a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like AutoCompleteSaveForm. But it's "IE only". So it's not a solution.